# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'read' --- HOW CAN I FIX?

Tags: python

My code:

```
import simpleaudio as sa
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import wave

raiz = Tk()
raiz.geometry("200x300")

#function that plays song -is not playing eith a function in parameters, only with the path
def add_song():
    song = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir='Downloads/', title="Escolha uma musica", filetypes=(("wav files", "*.wav"), ))

my_menu = Menu(raiz)
raiz.config(menu=my_menu)

addmusica_menu = Menu(my_menu)
my_menu.add_cascade(label="Adicionar", menu=addmusica_menu)
addmusica_menu.add_command(label="Uma Música", command=add_song)

def play():
    wave_read = wave.open(add_song, 'rb')
    wave_obj = sa.WaveObject.from_wave_read(wave_read)
    wave_obj = sa.WaveObject.from_wave_file(add_song)
    play_obj = wave_obj.play()

def stop():
    play_obj.stop()

Rightframe = Frame(raiz)
Rightframe.pack(pady=1)

middleframe = Frame(Rightframe)
middleframe.pack(pady=5, padx=5)

play_img = PhotoImage(file='botoes/play.png')
playBt = Button(middleframe, image=play_img, borderwidth=0, command=play)
playBt.grid(row=10, column=2, padx=5)

parar_img = PhotoImage(file='botoes/parar.png')
pararBt = Button(middleframe, image=parar_img, borderwidth=0, command=stop)
pararBt.grid(row=10, column=0, padx=5)

raiz.mainloop()
```

error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "playquefunciona.py", line 22, in play
    wave_read = wave.open(add_song, 'rb')
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\wave.py", line 510, in open
    return Wave_read(f)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\wave.py", line 164, in __init__
    self.initfp(f)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\wave.py", line 129, in initfp
    self._file = Chunk(file, bigendian = 0)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\chunk.py", line 61, in __init__
    self.chunkname = file.read(4)
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Comment: It is hard to understand your problem if you don't provide the traceback information of the error. Furthermore, your question should not be in the title. Instead ask the actual question at the correct position of the main body of your question

Comment: Did you mean `wave_read = wave.open(add_song(), 'rb')`?

Comment: yes, but i tested this right now and is not working either. its just opening the file dialog

Comment: Because you need to `return` something from `add_song`. Add `return song`

Comment: did this and its not working File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)'

Comment: Please read about [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [ask]. You can also use [Python-Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) which helps to visualize the execution of the code step-by-step.

Answer (score 0):

```
 wave_read = wave.open(add_song, 'rb')
```

in this line you are not calling the function add_song , and also in the function you are not returning anything

Comment: how i do this? i just started with python and programing in general